# Using function templates instead of template specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I am specializing template functions when intel intrinsic computation is available. In my case SSE and AVX. I want to produce a test program where I cal the non-specialized template function and the specialized one to compare performance. However, I do not know how to call the non-specialized template function for the type that it is specialized.

**Here is a simplified example:**

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void f(T val)
{
  std::cout << "Template function. Value: " << val << std::endl;
}

template <>
void f(float val)
{
  std::cout << "Float function. Value: " << val << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  f(1);
  f(1.0f);
  return 0;
}
```

**Question:** is there a way to call `f(1.0f)` with the non-specialized template function without changing function names?

**Clarification:** In my case, the two functions are provided in a library as part of the same pair of header and implementation file. Then this is included (for the template) and linked (for the specialization) in the program.

Comment: Call it before you specialize. Thats the only way and I don't even know whether its UB or not. Probably violates ODR.

Comment: The two functions are provided in a library as part of the same pair of header and implementation file. Then this is included (for the template) and linked (for the specialization) in the program. I do not know how to call it before it is specialized in this case.

Comment: Then you can't.

Comment: Could you provide a small explanation as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: [Why Not Specialize Function Templates](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

Comment: I do not understand your comment @Swordfish. I don't want to overload. I am using intel intrinsic and, if SSE or AVX is available I want to use the specialized implementation directly. I do not know how to distinguish between the implementation with SSE/AVX from the one without as both will be `f(float val)`.

Comment: @Swordfish, So here this is the opposite, why not overload the function template!

Comment: @apalomer You could differentiate the template from the non template overload by explicitly specifying the template argument: `f<float>(1.f)` would call the template, `f(1.f)` would call the non template

Comment: some wording nitpick: you can only call a specailzation of a template function, also your primary template gets specialized (by the compiler) before you can call it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add an extra parameter to prohibit specialization:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, bool enable_specialization = true>
void f(T val)
{
  std::cout << "Template function. Value: " << val << std::endl;
}

template <>
void f<float, true>(float val)
{
  std::cout << "Float function. Value: " << val << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  f(1.0f);
  f<float, false>(1.0f);
  return 0;
}
```

[online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rEvtT0BuCJAMntTF)

Answer (score 2):

Option N°2:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void f(T val)
{
  std::cout << "generic" << val << std::endl;
}


void f(float val)
{
  std::cout << "Target specific" << val << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  f(1); //=> generic
  f(1.0f); //=> target specific
  f<float>(1.0f); //=> generic
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this option. Shouldn't the compiler complain about a redefinition of `f(float val)` as they both have the same signature?

Comment: @apalomer. The signature of a template function includes the template parameters and the template arguments. [function signature, intro.defs/3.19](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.defs#defns.signature) [template function signature, intro.defs/3.20](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.defs#defns.signature.templ)

Comment: @apalomer Of interst also, when two functions are candidate and have the same function parameter types, the non template one is preferred [over.match.best/1.6](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#1.6)